# Flutter Agora - Is there any way to leave or end a broadcast stream when user kills the app from recent or discards app?

Tags: flutter, dart, webrtc, live-streaming, agora.io

I was trying out the agora flutter live streaming feature using **[agora_rtc_engine](https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtc_engine)** package and **flutter SDK 2.2.3**,

Everything seems to be working fine. But, there is no way to leave or end the stream or getting any callback to release the resources when a user removes or kills the app from recent apps.

I've tried **"didChangeAppLifecycleState"**, **"dispose"** methods of flutter framework as well.

Is there any way or agora team is able to manage this scenario anyway?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the latest version of the Agora SDK, where the channel is closed automatically when the user leaves the channel or destroys the application.

You can try using the Agora RESTful API to check and see if your channel is getting destroyed or not: https://docs.agora.io/en/rtc/restfulapi/#/Online%20channel%20statistics%20query/channelList